# Stuck in this Java program. Please explain Why EmployeeDetails is called in the EmpBusinessLogic.java class

Tags: java, encapsulation

I am learning Java Encapsulation now. I got stuck at the point where I saw these 2 programs.
Please explain to me how and why `EmployeeDetails` is called in the `EmpBusinessLogic.java` class.
That is,

```
public double calculateYearlySalary(EmployeeDetails employeeDetails)
```

In the line above, how is EmployDetails called in?
I am sorry for asking such a silly question, but i am stuck in here. 
Thanks a lot for the support!

**EmployeeDetails.java**

```
    public class EmployeeDetails {

           private String name;
           private double monthlySalary;
           private int age;

           // @return the name

           public String getName() {
              return name;
           }

           // @param name the name to set

           public void setName(String name) {
              this.name = name;
           }

           // @return the monthlySalary

           public double getMonthlySalary() {
              return monthlySalary;
           }

           // @param monthlySalary the monthlySalary to set

           public void setMonthlySalary(double monthlySalary) {
              this.monthlySalary = monthlySalary;
           }

           // @return the age

           public int getAge() {
              return age;
           }

           // @param age the age to set

           public void setAge(int age) {
           this.age = age;
           }
        }
```

**EmpBusinessLogic.java:**

```
 public class EmpBusinessLogic {

           // Calculate the yearly salary of employee
           public double calculateYearlySalary(EmployeeDetails employeeDetails) //How and Why EmployeeDetails is taken here?
{
              double yearlySalary = 0;
              yearlySalary = employeeDetails.getMonthlySalary() * 12;
              return yearlySalary;
           }

           // Calculate the appraisal amount of employee
           public double calculateAppraisal(EmployeeDetails employeeDetails){

              double appraisal = 0;

              if(employeeDetails.getMonthlySalary() < 10000){
                 appraisal = 500;

              }else{
                 appraisal = 1000;
              }

              return appraisal;
           }



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not called. Its like saying that you offer a service (in this case the service will be a double) and you want payment for it (payment is EmployDetails). Provided the EmployDetails you give the double. So when you want to call `calculateYearlySalary` you provide as an argument an instance of EmployDetails class and it gives you back (returns) the double.

Take a look at [Methods](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm) and [Objects](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm) where you can find more information about how Objects are created, and how they are "passed" to methods.

Answer (score 0):

That line `public double calculateYearlySalary(EmployeeDetails employeeDetails)` is a method definition.

First is access modifier `public`, second is return type `double`, then name of the method. After that in parentheses are parameters. Each parameter is divided using a comma. (for example `public int foo(int first, double second, boolean third)`). Each parameter consists of two parts. First is type of the parameter (in your example it's `EmployeeData`, in my example it's `int`, `double`, and `boolean`), second is name of the variable that will store the parameter (in your example `employeeDetails`, in my example `first`, `second` and `third`)

Comment: *"Each parameter consists of two "words"."* -> "Each parameter consists of _at least_ two "words".". There can be more than two.

Comment: Yeah, i should've said parts. I couldn't remember the word. -_- That's why it was in quotes

Comment: Well, if you call it "words" or "parts" is unrelated about that "at least" being missing ;P. A parameter can consist of more than just two parts.

Comment: I can remember only generics, variable length parameters and inner classes that require you to write more stuff. But all of this just modifies type. So it's still two parts: type and a name. I guess it depends on what you call part

Comment: No, it depends on why you think I'm talking about _required_ parts. That's not the case. Every parameter _can_ consists of more than the two mentioned parts. _Can_.

Comment: well.. you said, public int foo(int first, double second, boolean third), in this we have int, double, boolean. It makes sense. But how come we have EmployeeData?

Comment: @MohammedSajjad because `EmployeeData` is a type of an object. `boolean`, `double`, `int`, `long` `float` `short`, `byte` are primitive types. `EmployeeData` is an object type

Answer (score 0):

I would create static functions in the `EmployeeBusinessLogic` as business logic appears to be more of utility functions.

Example code here:

```
package general;

public class EmployeeBusinessLogic {
    // Calculate the yearly salary of employee
    public static double  calculateYearlySalary(EmployeeDetails employeeDetails) { //How and Why EmployeeDetails is taken here?
        double yearlySalary = 0;
        yearlySalary = employeeDetails.getMonthlySalary() * 12;
        return yearlySalary;
    }

    // Calculate the appraisal amount of employee
    public static double calculateAppraisal(EmployeeDetails employeeDetails){
        double appraisal = 0;
        if (employeeDetails.getMonthlySalary() < 10000) {
            appraisal = 500;
        } else {
            appraisal = 1000;
        }
        return appraisal;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EmployeeDetails emp1 = new EmployeeDetails();
        emp1.setAge(30);
        emp1.setName("Rob Dylan");
        emp1.setMonthlySalary(4000);
        System.out.println("Annual salary of " + emp1.getName() + " is " + calculateYearlySalary(emp1));
    }
}
```

Output is as follows:

> Annual salary of Rob Dylan is 48000.0

Answer (score 0):

WHY:

So that you can use the methods of EmployeeDetails class.

In order to access the information about an  employee in the methods of your EmpBusinessLogic class you need to pass an EmployeeDetails object,So now based on this object you calculate yearly salary of that employee and similarly of other employees

How:
first you make objects of EmployeeDetails Class and fill in all the information.

```
EmployeeDetails details=new EmployeeDetails()
details.setMonthlySalary(22222.22);
```

next you make a EmpBusinessLogic object

now when you call the methods of this class you can pass EmployeeDetails objects and get the salary details and other stuff

```
EmpBusinessLogic logic=new EmpbusinessLogic();
System.out.println(logic.calculateYearlySalary(EmployeeDetails details));
```